# Java drawing shape to bufferedImage from outside paintComponent()?

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, graphics2d

This has probably been asked a bit but I need help with drawing shapes.
So I have my Draw class which extends `JPanel`.

I want to be able to draw an oval from outside the `paintComponent();` method.
So to load all my images I try to draw the shapes to a `BufferedImage`.
But I don't have a proper Graphics object.

So my question is: How would I get a proper Graphics object to draw to my `JPanel` with, or how would I draw inside the `paintComponent` method and be able to call it from another class?

Answer (score 3):

You get a Graphics object from the BufferedImage via `getGraphics()` or a Graphics2D object via `createGraphics()`. You then draw the image within paintComponent by calling drawImage  on its Graphics parameter.
Do dispose the BufferedImage's Graphics object when you're done using it since you created it. Do not dispose the Graphics object passed into paintComponent since the JVM made it.

Answer (score 2):

> How would I get a proper Graphics object to draw to my JPanel with, or how would I draw inside the paintComponent method and be able to call it from another class?

You don't.  You should never call any `paint` method manually.  There's a lot going on in the background which you don't control when a component is painted this way.

If you want to "print" a component, then you should be using `paintAll`.

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
componentToBePrinted.printAll(g2d);
g2d.dispose();
```

An alternative would be to use a `BufferedImage` and paint to it instead...

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g2d.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 10, 80, 80));
g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 10, 80, 80));
g2d.dispose();
```

You could then have a component paint it using `Graphics#drawImage`